# Insert text to editor, when focus is not in the div editor

Tags: javascript

I want to insert some text into the editor. But the focus is not inside the editor(div contenteditable="true").
How can i insert text before cursor is shown.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, in this case editor is the html `div` element you are using.

```
editor.innerHTML = 'my new content'
```